# Which trigonometric function to use?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Which function do I need to use to calculate the length of a side on an Isosceles triangle if I know $3$ angles and $1$ side?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) $$\frac{a}{\sin \hat{A}}=\frac{b}{\sin \hat B}=\frac{c}{\sin \hat C}(=2R)$$

Comment: Does it matter whether the angles go on top or bottom?

Comment: And shouldn't that say b over sin B?

Comment: @Charlie No. The fraction will be inversed but the theorem will be Ok. Yeah. I will fix it